# Vagrant ubuntu/trusty64 apache2.4.7 not showing *.css files

Tags: virtualbox, apache2, vagrant

I have virtual environment in Vagrant `ubuntu/trusty64`. Used phalcon framework.
Have install

```
> apache2 -v
Server version: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   Jan 14 2016 17:45:23
```

/etc/apache2/sites-avaliable/mysite.conf

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.33.10:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /vagrant/
    ServerName site.loc
    ServerAlias www.site.loc
    <Directory /vagrant/>
        AllowOverride All
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        Require all granted
        EnableMMAP Off
        EnableSendFile off
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

html file 
/public/index.php

```
<!doctype html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/src/css/test.css" type="text/css">
  </head>
  <body>

  </body>
</html>
```

css file
/src/css/test.css

```
body {
  background: red;
}
```

.htaccess
/.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^$ public/ [L]
  RewriteRule (.*) public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: And your page (html) itself is loaded, but the css code is ignored? If so - please add your page code (html and css) to your post as well

Comment: It is very big files. And yes html loaded but css code is ignored.

Comment: Well then use some kind of paste service - example: http://paste.ubuntu.com/ You Could as well slim your problem down first, which is a common way to simplify a problem to the essential core (shrink it down to the essential)

Comment: My main point is: if the problem is in your html or css, then add it, otherwise its hard to help. If your website itself is loaded, then the problem is most likely not coming from the apache setup.

Comment: And add the apache error log as well ;)

Comment: If css file is in the same directory something and html its working.

On another server this site work correctly(windows opesserver). Apache not show error

Comment: Check if the css file is readable for the webserver (permissions). And please add the error log. Consider as well opening the developer console of your browser to debug your page.

Comment: Apache not show error. In the console i have this error :Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://site.loc/src/css/test.css".
permissions 777

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem putting my src folder in the same directory as the index.php